# Can you use v3 Azure Functions with Entity Framework Core 3.0?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, azure-functions

I am trying to use EF Core 3 in the latest (preview) version of Azure functions, but I am getting the following error when I try interacting with the database:

> System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: DemoFunction. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.

I have a web app in the same solution that works just fine with the same setup, and there is nothing special about my "platform". This is the output from `dotnet --info`:

> .NET Core SDK (reflecting any global.json):  Version:
>   3.1.100-preview2-014569  Commit:    4bd5d24d87
>
> Runtime Environment:  OS Name:     Windows  OS Version:  10.0.18362 
>   OS Platform: Windows  RID:         win10-x64  Base Path:   C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100-preview2-014569\
>
> Host (useful for support):   Version: 3.1.0-preview2.19525.6   Commit:
>   5672978d91
>
> .NET Core SDKs installed:
>     2.1.801 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>     2.1.802 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>     3.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>     3.1.100-preview2-014569 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
>
> .NET Core runtimes installed:   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.12
>   [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.1.13 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.All]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.12 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 3.1.0-preview2.19528.8 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
>   2.1.12 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 2.1.13 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App
>   3.0.0 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]   Microsoft.NETCore.App 3.1.0-preview2.19525.6 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.0.0 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]
>   Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App 3.1.0-preview2.19525.6 [C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App]

I have created a minimal reproduction of the issue [here](https://github.com/benm-eras/SqlClientNotSupportedDemo), just start up the functions project and send it an HTTP request (same with the web app).

Is it currently possible to use EF Core 3 with v3 Azure Functions? (FYI I have a v2 Functions app running with EF Core 2.1)

Comment: Apparently the azure functions core tools team is working on a fix. https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1642

Comment: thanks! looks like there is a [workaround](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1370#issuecomment-545655510) that solves my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been solved , copy OP's comment , it will be helpful for others have similar issue :

> looks like there is a [workaround](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1370#issuecomment-545655510) that solves my issue

As a workaround, add the following code to .csproj:

```
<Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="copy $(OutDir)$(ProjectName).deps.json $(OutDir)bin\function.deps.json" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="PostPublish" BeforeTargets="Publish">
    <Exec Command="copy $(PublishDir)$(ProjectName).deps.json $(PublishDir)bin\function.deps.json" />
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another fix is to move from Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.8" back to 3.0.7
Reference: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1370#issuecomment-654698010